# Center taskbar icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I would like to center my taskbar icons similar to the Mac dock.  Is this possible?

It is. Here are my results:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: http://mintywhite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=1816&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

1. Start by creating an empty folder in Documents.
2. Right click on the Taskbar and unlock the Taskbar.
3. Right click again, go to Toolbars > New toolbar.
4. Select the folder you created a second ago and click on Select Folder.
   You'll see that the folder is now on the taskbar.
5. Right click the slider next to the new toolbar and uncheck Show title.
6. Click and drag the same slider as far left as possible.
7. The slider next to the Start Orb, click and drag to the right, until the pinned icons are just offset the the right.
8. Right click the taskbar and lock the taskbar.

NOTE:The icons will jump to the left slightly after locking so make sure that you offset them a bit to the right.

Comment: That's a terrible hack, but unfortunately that's probably the closest you'll get...

Comment: And way to make their advertisement. Any name will fit for the folder, doesn't have to be theirs.

Comment: Yeah I just copied and pasted from their site. I'll edit it. Like musicfreak said, it's an ugly hack anyway.

Comment: This is a decent solution. It would be nice if I could "center justify" the taskbar like in word processors, as I have to manually recenter the taskbar every time I add a new icon. Thanks though.